# Expression must be a value expression but is a method expression error in jsf 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am new to jsf. I write a simple application to retrive data from the database. I am calling a method in xhtml form but it is giving me the error as follow

```
Expression must be a value expression but is a method 
 expression
```

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  >
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css"  />
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h1>JSF 2.0 + JDBC Example</h1>

    <h:dataTable value="#{member.getMemberList()}" var="mem"
            styleClass="order-table"
            headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
        >

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Customer ID
            </f:facet>
                #{mem.FirstName}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Name
            </f:facet>
                #{mem.LastName}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Email
            </f:facet>
                #{mem.Email}
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Password
            </f:facet>
                #{mem.Password}
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Error at this line

```
<h:dataTable value="#{member.getMemberList()}" var="mem"
            styleClass="order-table"
            headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
        >
```

can any on help me to solve this error. I shall be thankful ...... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In managed bean **member** check if property **memberList** has both getter and setter. Then replace datatable code with:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{member.memberList}" var="mem"
            styleClass="order-table"
            headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
        >
```

Hope it helps.